# Expected a value of type 'SkDeletable', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have updated my flutter project from 1.26.3 to 2.1.0. Since then I am facing some issue. I am getting error as "Expected a value of type 'SkDeletable', but got one of type 'Null'".

Does anybody knows what is related with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved after I did `"flutter pub upgrade"`.
All dependency errors got resolved after upgrading pub.

Answer (score 15):

I got the same error with the following code snippet:

```
BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(
        
          sigmaX: animation.value * 5.0),
          sigmaY: animation.value * 5.0),
        ),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
```

The error gets thrown because the animation goes from 0 to 1. More precisely, the ImageFilter does not work with values equal to zero.
A quick work-around is something like:

```
max(0.001, animation.value * 5.0)
```

so no zero value is passed to the Filter.

Answer (score 2):

If you run your project in release or profile the error probably won't exist:

```
flutter run -d chrome --profile
flutter run -d chrome --release
```

At the same time if you get your --debug app and open it in Safari (for example) the error won't exist (most probably). It seems like an issue with Chrome (again).

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely related to flushbar lib you might be using, try to use another_flushbar, as it has this problem solved and has the same api.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my running the following commands on the terminal

- `flutter clean`
- `flutter pub get`
- `flutter run`
  I hope it resolves your issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in flutter and has been reported in this issue.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77258